# Intellij doesn't show proper android documentation

Tags: android, intellij-idea, intellij-13

Intellij shows only method signature and not proper documentation as in eclipse.
And no docs in layout, no proper details in any android related object

This is all pointing to **Quick Documentation** shortcut

I have already tried to attach android docs to intellij, but to no result

Using Intellij 13.1 and maven project

Since working in intellij I have to go visit developer's site for any detail regarding any info

Is there a way to get android docs as in **eclipse**

Comment: Try to move focus on Object and use Ctrl+Spacebar.

Comment: No use, it still shows object related extends and implements classes

Comment: Can you please try Shift+f1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Perform the following steps:

1. Goto File > Settings > Editor. Click on the checkbox, to show docs on mouse hover. Click OK.
2. Now on mouse hover, press `CTRL+SHIFT+SPACEBAR`.